# Errors/Warnings in Ruby Wordnet Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, warnings, wordnet

I've noticed that there are a lot of errors/warnings with the ruby Wordnet gem.

Does anybody know how to get rid of them? Or if the Wordnet gem is being actively maintained? There also seems to be errors using the Wordnet gem with Ruby 1.9.2 (which I've been able to get around following steps in https://gist.github.com/1779371)

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question, but there's a few answers in questions tagged "ruby" and "warnings" about how to suppress warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at the [rwordnet](http://doches.github.com/rwordnet/) gem instead?